# What other numeric systems are there?

Tags: numeric

There's binary, decimal, hexadecimal, anything else?

Answer (score 6):

[Octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (base-8) is another popular one, but there are infinitely many numeric systems.

For example, in Excel the columns are labeled in [hexavigesimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexavigesimal) (base-26).

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numeral_systems) is a list of popular positional numeric systems.

Then you also have other numeric systems that aren't positional, such as [Chinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_numerals) and [Roman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) numeral systems, but I'm guessing by your examples that you meant strictly positional numeric systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any base you like to represent numbers, though it becomes difficult once you move beyond the alphanumeric characters. On the other hand, if you consider a single byte as a "digit", then most (unsigned) integral numbers are stored in base-256 within a computer.

That being said, the only widely-used number system aside from those listed (that I'm aware of) is **Octal**, which is base-8.

Answer (score 1):

The Babylonians liked base 60 (sexagesimal)...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_numerals

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many...check out the Wikipedia page for Arity (specifically n-ary):

[Arity - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ary)

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of bases for integers (with pretty much everyone knowing base 10).

Also complex, real, & rational.

[Wikipedia Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number)

Answer (score 1):

A numbering system can be formed for any Number n, where n need only be an element of the Hamiltonians or any subset thereof the digits then correspond to the form

`{n^k0, n^k0-1, n^k0 -2, ... n^0}.(radix point){n^-1, n^-2, ...,n^k1}
Where k0 is the High order of magnitude, and k1 is the precision`